# Pandas- ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found error code

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this code, where i concatenate 12 csv files and I choose the desired columns from the concatenated file and then re-save it, my problem is when I have some columns it works fine, but when i start choosing more columns I get the following error, I will upload the code before and after along with the error.

This code works fine

```
import pandas as pd
import glob


#combine all csv files into one csv file

files = glob.glob(r'/Users/AliOsama/Desktop/Project/database/*.csv')


combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['Power_kW','ReactivePower_kVAr','WindSpeed_mps','YawState','Pitch_Deg','RotorSpeed_rpm','AmbTemp_DegC','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','SubIprPrivPwrFactor', 'SubPtchPosition1', 'SubPtchPosition2', 'SubPtchPosition3'']) for file in files])

combined_csv.fillna(combined_csv.mean(), inplace=True)



combined_csv.to_csv(r'/Users/AliOsama/Desktop/Project/database/combineddd.csv', index=False)
```

This code gives me an error:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob


#combine all csv files into one csv file

files = glob.glob(r'/Users/AliOsama/Desktop/Project/database/*.csv')


combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['Power_kW','ReactivePower_kVAr','WindSpeed_mps','YawState','Pitch_Deg','RotorSpeed_rpm','AmbTemp_DegC','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','SubIprPrivPwrFactor', 'SubPtchPosition1', 'SubPtchPosition2', 'SubPtchPosition3', 'Volts1_Vrms', 'Volts2_Vrms', 'Volts3_Vrms']) for file in files])

combined_csv.fillna(combined_csv.mean(), inplace=True)



combined_csv.to_csv(r'/Users/AliOsama/Desktop/Project/database/combineddd.csv', index=False)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-143f65dcf76b> in <module>
      8 
      9 
---> 10 combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file,dtype='unicode' , usecols=['Power_kW','ReactivePower_kVAr','WindSpeed_mps','YawState','Pitch_Deg','RotorSpeed_rpm','AmbTemp_DegC','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','SubIprPrivPwrFactor', 'SubPtchPosition1', 'SubPtchPosition2', 'SubPtchPosition3', 'Volts1_Vrms', 'Volts2_Vrms', 'Volts3_Vrms']) for file in files])
     11 
     12 combined_csv.fillna(combined_csv.mean(), inplace=True)

<ipython-input-7-143f65dcf76b> in <listcomp>(.0)
      8 
      9 
---> 10 combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file,dtype='unicode' , usecols=['Power_kW','ReactivePower_kVAr','WindSpeed_mps','YawState','Pitch_Deg','RotorSpeed_rpm','AmbTemp_DegC','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','SubIprPrivPwrFactor', 'SubPtchPosition1', 'SubPtchPosition2', 'SubPtchPosition3', 'Volts1_Vrms', 'Volts2_Vrms', 'Volts3_Vrms']) for file in files])
     11 
     12 combined_csv.fillna(combined_csv.mean(), inplace=True)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    438 
    439     # Create the parser.
--> 440     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    441 
    442     if chunksize or iterator:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    785             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    786 
--> 787         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    788 
    789     def close(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1012     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1013         if engine == 'c':
-> 1014             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1015         else:
   1016             if engine == 'python':

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1747             if (self.usecols_dtype == 'string' and
   1748                     not set(usecols).issubset(self.orig_names)):
-> 1749                 _validate_usecols_names(usecols, self.orig_names)
   1750 
   1751             if len(self.names) > len(usecols):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _validate_usecols_names(usecols, names)
   1132         raise ValueError(
   1133             "Usecols do not match columns, "
-> 1134             "columns expected but not found: {missing}".format(missing=missing)
   1135         )
   1136 

ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Volts1_Vrms', 'Volts3_Vrms', 'Volts2_Vrms']
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! That error seems to be telling you that those 3 columns don't exist in the DF you're trying to concat. Have you verified that they exist in both dataframes?

Comment: @G.Anderson I ran like the description code to know all the columns inside the 12 csv files and they all have the same columns.

Comment: @G.Anderson so I discover that out of the 12 csv files, 2 of them have the column but they are empty, I still need to concatenate the rest , but I have no clue to how concatenate everything without these 2 columns in these 2 files.

Comment: You can use `try: except:` to concatenate the files that _do_ have data, but as for how to handle the files that don't contain the data, that will depend on what you need for the end goal you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you very much, working now.